# export bootstrap table not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

[image: Here is the order in which files are loaded filtered by table]

[image: another image of loads filtered by bootstrap]

```
<table id="table2b"
   data-show-export="true"
   data-toggle="table"
   data-height="350"
   data-search="true" 
   data-show-columns="true">
```

I am trying to make export work like this https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/extensions/export.html
but I cannot see the export button.

Comment: Got your some errors in console?

Comment: no no error in console.

Comment: Are you include jQuery on your site?

Comment: yes including jquery 2.1.4 Actually i am seeing i am including jquery-ui twice, I don't know if that can cause issue let me remove and check.

Comment: I removed extra jquery-ui js didn't make any difference